# if a cxBarEditItem1 is a checkbox, how to get it's state?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

On my dxBarManager1Bar1 a cxBarEditItem1 is a checkbox.
How can I check it's state (if it's checked or not checked) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accomplishing your task, you can use the `EditValue` property.

```
if (cxBarEditItem1.EditValue <> Null) AND (cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = True) then 
  ShowMessage('Checked!')
else 
  ShowMessage('Not Checked! (or null)');
```

Note that EditValue is a `Variant` property which can also have `Null` value.

Comment: Thank you... Googled for some time but could not find an answer.

Comment: I've just googled now, and found the answer https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T158422

Comment: @user3351050: Please accept the answer, if it helped