# Why is this procedure not working properly?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

This I run on button click :

```
procedure TMain_Form.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (trim(cxmemo1.lines.Text) = '')  then  begin
    showmessage('Memo is empty');
    abort;
  end else begin
    if cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = False then begin   //this does not execute
      showmessage('No user');
      abort;
    end else begin
      DataModule.MYQUERY.Close;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.SQL.Clear;
      DataModule.UniTransaction1.AddConnection(DataModule.UniConnection1);
      DataModule.UniTransaction1.StartTransaction;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO MYTABLE (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5) VALUES(:p1,:p2,:p3,0,:p4);');
      DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p1').asDate :=cxDateNavigator1.date;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p2').asDateTime := Now;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p3').Value :=cxMemo1.Lines.Text ;
      if cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = True then
        DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p4').asString := dxStatusbar1.Panels[1].Text
      else
        DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p4').asString := cxLookUpComboBox1.Text;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.Prepare;
      DataModule.MYQUERY.ExecSQL;
      try
        DataModule.UniTransaction1.Commit;
      except on E:exception do
        begin
          DataModule.UniTransaction1.Rollback;
          raise exception.create('Error: '+e.message);
        end;
      end;
      DataModule.UniStoredProc2.Refresh;
      cxMemo1.Lines.Clear;
      cxMemo1.SetFocus;
      cxLabel2.Caption:='';
      AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Enabled:=False;
      AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Visible:=False;
      cxLookUpComboBox1.Clear;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The first part,where it checks if the memo is empty, executes OK.
If it is empty the procedure is aborted.

However, the second condition (where it should check state of the checkbox), does not.It just fires up the query.

Somewhere I probably messed the if then statement but cant figure where. Please help ...

Comment: Have you done any debugging. Does your code look like that? Without indentation?

Comment: Fixing your indentation is the first and by far the _easiest_ step in spotting "if then" logical errors quickly.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with cxBarEditItem1.EditValue and inspect the value of cxBarEditItem1.EditValue. Then you'll know the problem

Comment: Do you really want to use **Abort** to exit your procedure?

Comment: In addition to the good advice here - to simply put a breakpoint and see what's going on - you could also pay attention to the previous answer you got on this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41297085/327083

Comment: When `cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = False ` doesn't execute when you are expecting it to, does the checkbox display an empty box, or one containing a black square?  And what happens if you set the `EditValue` to False immediately before `if cxBarEditItem1.EditValue ...`?

Comment: Once again, https://twitter.com/rkennedy/status/365678718993170433

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can start this way :

```
procedure TMain_Form.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (trim(cxmemo1.lines.Text) = '')  then 
  begin
    showmessage('Memo is empty');
    abort; //you can also use exit instead of abort
  end 
  else 
    if cxLookUpComboBox1.Text = '' then 
    begin
      showmessage('user is empty');
      abort;  //you can also use exit instead of abort
    end  
  else  
  begin
    ...
```

Remove the lines :

```
if cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = True then
  DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p4').asString := dxStatusbar1.Panels[1].Text
else
  DataModule.MYQUERY.Params.ParamByName('p4').asString := cxLookUpComboBox1.Text;
```

Then do :

```
procedure TMain_Form.cxBarEditItem1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cxBarEditItem1.EditValue = True then  
  begin
    cxLookUpComboBox1.Text := dxStatusbar1.Panels[1].Text;
    cxLookUpComboBox1.Enabled:=False; //just in case value does not get changed
  end 
  else 
  begin
    cxLookUpComboBox1.Text :='';
    cxLookUpComboBox1.Enabled:=True;
  end;
end;
```

Just my 2 cents ...

edit: removed application.processmessages as not needed.

edi2: sorry,first part was wrong (cut&paste hurry). Corrected.

Comment: If you need `application.ProcessMessages` then usually you are doing something wrong.  Also in a properly working gui, there should be no need for "just in case" measures.

Comment: sometimes events dont fire when we expect them to. combo might get disabled before text arrives. no harm done :)

Comment: "No harm done". Not so. "Sometimes events don't fire when we expect then to". What on earth are you talking about? This is a really poor answer.

Comment: @ David Heffernan - I had some time ago issues with devexpress components like that.

Comment: the issue was when the cxBarEdit item was part of dxBarPopupMenu1.

Comment: went back to old code.now under 15.2.3 it works Ok so no need to process anything.

Comment: The first code example makes no sense, you have else and again else

Comment: @ David Heffernan - Obviously there's some kind of sync between cxLookupcomboBox1 and cxBarEditItem1 since 
parameters change. Enabling the cxLookupcomboBox1 might disrupt the sync.

Comment: I'd you don't understand something don't just throw in random calls to ProcessMessages and invent some half baked explanation.

Comment: sorry, my bad ... it was an issue from long time ago.

Comment: @GuidoG - Thank you ...corrected...

Comment: @user763539 I dont see any correction. You still have one else that never ever can be reached

Comment: @GuidoD - why not ? abort resorts to beginning - exit continues the flow. Why cant it be reached? Tried and works.Not sure I understan you right ...

Comment: @user763539 The problem is not the abort or the exit. The problem is that you have an if followed by an else, and followed by another else. That second else cannot be reached because it will either go into the if or into the first else, never in the second else. The one with the ...